# Comparison between fat-matrix

Tags: r, intraclass-correlation, chemometrics

I have two data sets obtained from two different kind of chemical analysis: GC-MS and IR. Both the chemical analysis were performed using the same samples. My aim is to know if there are some relations between GC-MS data and IR data.

The data sets are two 'fat' matrix where: number of columns (objects) > number of rows (different samples). R is the way I use to analyze them.

Which is the better approach for this kind of work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for *multiblock analysis*.

[Achim Kohler's publications](http://arken.umb.no/~achik/peer_rev.html) and Harald Martens' work could be a good starting point I think.

For more specific advise we'd need more information, e.g.

- Do you have a 1:1 correspondence between the matrix rows (i.e. 1 IR and 1 GC-MS spectrum per sample)?
- Do you want to relate GC-MS and IR data only or will it ultimately be related to other (dependent) variates?
  (you tagged the question with "classes")
- It may also help if you'd roughly outline the application you're working at.